# How to get values from dynamically created input box in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Here i have written some code for getting values from dynamically created input box using javascript

Below is the Code for setting value:

```
    for(var i=0;i<result.studentlist.length;i++){


     var addtxt = document
                                        .createElement("input");

                                        addtxt.type = "text";
                                        addtxt.name = "admissionno" ;
                                        addtxt.id = "admissionno" ;
                                        addtxt.value = result.studentlist[i].admissionno;

}
```

And getting purpose written below code:

```
var admissionNumber=document.getElementById("admissionno").value;
```

Actually two Admission numbers appended.

But, when am getting value at that time only first value is coming.

please give me an idea.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("admissionno")` will always provide you a single element since ids are unique and the function also returns a single DOM element.

You should instead add classes and use them like `document.getElementByClassName("classname")`. It will return you a Node List through which you can iterate over.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter id must be unique. A solution will be:

Generation:

```
for(var i=0;i<result.studentlist.length;i++){
    var addtxt = document.createElement("input");
    addtxt.type = "text";
    addtxt.name = "admissionno" ;
    addtxt.id = "admissionno"+i ;
    addtxt.value = result.studentlist[i].admissionno;
}
```

Collecting data (assuming you want to put all together):

```
var inputs=document.getElementsByName("admissionno");
var admissionNumber="";
for (var j=0;j<inputs.length;j++) {
    admissionNumber+=inputs[j].value+" ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the input elements in a form to get multiple values at the same time.
Also, if I am not mistaken you are creating duplicate id's with your code. 
What you want is:

```
document.getElementsByName("admissiono")
```

This method returns you an array of elements which can be iterated over. 
Or you can access certain positions with:

```
document.getElementsByName("admissiono")[0].value
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML element id should be unique.I suppose that u should give the element different ids first.Then get each value of them.